# Insert function calls more than one for same date and time

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert, smtp

I'm creating a "Leave Management System".

When user apply for leave then leave inserted into database then notification mail send specific person.

Problem: sometimes the same leave request is inserted more than once for the same date and time.

To prevent that, I added

```
  if (flag2 == true)
```

first, add then send mail, but I still have that problem - but not every time, but a few times.

I think that may be because of send mail required more time.

```
    protected void duration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {       
   
               srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_Id"].DefaultValue = txtleaveid.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_EmpId"].DefaultValue = txtempid.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_EmpName"].DefaultValue = TextBox11.Text + " (" + Label20.Text + ")";
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_ReportingOfficer"].DefaultValue = TextBox23.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_Department"].DefaultValue = TextBox21.Text + '-' + TextBox24.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_Type"].DefaultValue = DropDownList1.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_StartDate"].DefaultValue = txtStartDate.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_EndDate"].DefaultValue = txtEndDate.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_Duration"].DefaultValue = txtduration.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_Remarks"].DefaultValue = txtremarks.Text;
                //srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_ApplicationDate"].DefaultValue = TextBox2.Text;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_ApplicationDate"].DefaultValue = app_date_time;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Leave_Location"].DefaultValue = Label21.Text; ;
                srcLeaveDetails.InsertParameters["Emp_Centre"].DefaultValue = Labe_mainlocation.Text;

            bool flag = false;
            try
            {
                srcLeaveDetails.Insert();                  
              
                flag = true;
                Label14.Text = "Your Leave Request has been recorded";

                
            }
            catch (SqlException s)
            {

                // Response.Write(s.Message);
                Label14.Text = " Error! Please Try Again";
            }
         
            if(flag==true)
                sendMail();  
            

     }
```

Mail function

```
 public void sendMail()
   {
try
   {
        
       using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(" ", " "))
            {
                mm.Subject = "Email-Notification of Leave for approval ";
                mm.Body = ""
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("", "");
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Timeout = 2000000;
                smtp.Send(mm);
   }catch(exception ex){} }
```

Comment: You need to provide us the complete code to understand how are you calling this implementation

Comment: Don't double click the "apply for leave" button?

Comment: Why does your code only send a mail if an error occurs?

Comment: @viveknuna added completed function on button click please check

Comment: @CaiusJard i set flag==true so on error not send any mail only with successfully inserted

Comment: Oh, sorry - either the way the code was formatted or the way it showed on the phone (the mobile site is getting worse these days) I couldn't see the closing bracket of the empty catch- it looked like the mail send was inside the catch

Comment: Soo.. how many times are you clicking the button (or if it's deployed, how many times are the *users* clicking the button? Are you aware that there are some people out there that think buttons need to be double clicked? Maybe try disabling the button as the first line of the Click handler, do a Applicarion.DoEvents to make it look disabled while you process, then enable it again at the end (no need for DoEvents) - using TAP would be better, of course, but it's a lot more work

Comment: If you're certain the code is not being invoked twice then we need to see the Insert()  method impl

Comment: @CaiusJard  no i am sure about that because we provided user side validation so any one double click required message occurs I used this system last one year without mail  only this time when I added mail send code and then this happen

Comment: Perhaps the email caused the method to take longer time, causing the users to press the button twice since they do not know if the first click registered? Always have some feedback to the user for any operation taking longer than ~50ms. This should be trivial to determine by adding logging so you can see what has happened after the problem has occurred. Without more information we can only guess at the reason.

Comment: In the interest of good user UI experience you should be making these calls async anyway, but like I said, if you're certain there can be no possible way for the user to invoke this twice then we need to see the content of the Insert method - you're asserting "there can be no way" but you haven't shown the method. If there is no way the code in Insert can insert twice without being invoked twice, I'll revert to my original theory: your user is clicking the button twice

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov any simple way to solve this